# MACROs in C++ to auto-generate a variable

Tags: c++, macros, intel

I have the code below, which is a [pintool](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool) I am writing in `C++` this is a part of a [code](https://svn.mcs.anl.gov/repos/performance/Gwalp/gwalpsite/pin/source/tools/Memory/allcache.cpp) that generates the ITLB part, of a single-core system. I am trying to adjust the code above, to make it work with multiple cores (for example 4)

```
#define CORE_NUM 4

namespace ITLB
{
    // instruction TLB: 4 kB pages, 32 entries, fully associative
    const UINT32 lineSize = 4*KILO;
    const UINT32 cacheSize = 32 * lineSize;
    const UINT32 associativity = 32;
    const CACHE_ALLOC::STORE_ALLOCATION allocation = CACHE_ALLOC::STORE_ALLOCATE;

    const UINT32 max_sets = cacheSize / (lineSize * associativity);
    const UINT32 max_associativity = associativity;

    typedef CACHE_ROUND_ROBIN(max_sets, max_associativity, allocation) CACHE;
}
LOCALVAR ITLB::CACHE itlb("ITLB 0", ITLB::cacheSize, ITLB::lineSize, ITLB::associativity);
```

i want to auto-generate the following:

```
LOCALVAR ITLB::CACHE itlb_0("ITLB 0", ITLB::cacheSize, ITLB::lineSize, ITLB::associativity);
LOCALVAR ITLB::CACHE itlb_1("ITLB 1", ITLB::cacheSize, ITLB::lineSize, ITLB::associativity);
LOCALVAR ITLB::CACHE itlb_2("ITLB 2", ITLB::cacheSize, ITLB::lineSize, ITLB::associativity);
LOCALVAR ITLB::CACHE itlb_3("ITLB 3", ITLB::cacheSize, ITLB::lineSize, ITLB::associativity);
```

because of the CORE_NUM = 4. A possible solution is `MACROS` I guess! Any help?
I am not very familiar using MACROs, could anyone suggest me a possible solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to produce variable names ending with a serial number is with macros. However, this approach generally complicates your code. Using something that you can index is cleaner and is my recommendation. As Peter Cordes indicates, when the size is known at compile time and performance is critical, a fixed size array should be the best choice. In other circumstances, a std::vector or some other collection class may be appropriate.

Note: LOCALVAR appears to expand to static. If you wish to restrict access to your variables to a single source file, you will have to adapt my examples appropriately.

Alternative 1:

C++11, avoids preprocessor complexities, uses std::vector.

*To substitute a fixed size array for the std::vector and not get into the preprocessor would require ITLB::CACHE to have a default constructor (not currently the case) and be correctly copy assignable (not checked).*

In .h:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
// other includes

#define CORE_NUM 4

class ItlbCachePool
{
public:
    ItlbCachePool() 
    {
        std::string namePrefix("ITLB ");
        for ( std::size_t i = 0; i < CORE_NUM; ++i )
        {
            pool.emplace_back( 
                namePrefix + std::to_string(i), 
                ITLB::cacheSize, 
                ITLB::lineSize, 
                ITLB::associativity);
        }
    }

    ITLB::CACHE &operator[](std::size_t index)       
    { 
        return pool[index]; 
    }

    const ITLB::CACHE &operator[](std::size_t index) const 
    { 
        return pool[index]; 
    }

private:
    std::vector<ITLB::CACHE> pool;
};

extern ItlbCachePool itlibs;
```

In .cpp

```
// ...
ItlbCachePool itlibs;
```

Usage:

```
const BOOL itlbHit = itlbs[coreIndex].AccessSingleLine(addr, accessType);
```

You may wish to add bounds checking to this and turn it into a singleton. You might also adapt this to allow for run-time determination of the number of cores.

Do note that after construction, there is no way to add elements to the private vector. This keeps the vector from re-allocating and invalidating any pointers/references to vector elements some client code might have created.

Alternative 2:

Produces a bare array, requires Boost library to handle preprocessor complexities:

In .h

```
#define CORE_NUM 4
extern ITLB::CACHE itlbs[CORE_NUM];
```

In .cpp

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/iteration/local.hpp>

// white space required before "(" on next line
#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_LIMITS     (0, CORE_NUM - 1)
#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_MACRO(n)   \
    ITLB::CACHE( \
    "ITLB " #n, ITLB::cacheSize, ITLB::lineSize, ITLB::associativity),
ITLB::CACHE itlbs[] = 
    {
#include BOOST_PP_LOCAL_ITERATE()
    };
```

Usage:

```
const BOOL itlbHit = itlbs[coreIndex].AccessSingleLine(addr, accessType);
```

Comment: If `CORE_NUM` is a compile-time constant, you'll get better code for most use-cases with an array, not a vector.  It's one less level of indirection, and your `ItlbCachePool` becomes a POD type (at least if you replace the `std::string` with a `const char*`, which might also be a good idea.)

Comment: @PeterCordes agreed. I poked around at the OP's links to the Intel code he is using and found that ITLB::CACHE resolves to a class without a default constructor. I went with a vector here since "auto-generating" the initialization for the array would require more complicated preprocessor stuff. Admittedly, macros are what the OP was literally asking for. (FWIW, the constructor expects a std::string argument.)

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot that he said this was for use with Intel's PIN stuff.  Having each object keep a `std::string` seems insane to me, which is why my answer suggested dropping it altogether and determining identity with `current - start_of_array`.  I think my suggestion is a lot cleaner if it's viable while still solving the ultimate problem of using the PIN API (which I haven't looked at).

Comment: i really cant understand the code.
I want to use `itlb_0` and `itlb_1` where have they been generated?

for example I am using that:

`const BOOL itlbHit = ((threadid % 2)  == 0 ? itlb_0.AccessSingleLine(addr, accessType) : itlb_1.AccessSingleLine(addr, accessType));`

Comment: @taleporos They haven't been. I've tried to make my post clearer. My suggestion/recommendation is not to use CORE_NUM differently named variables, but one object that you can index into. It will make the rest of your code more manageable and maintainable.

Comment: @taleporos  If you must use the separate variable approach and can use Boost, my second alternative can be modified to do it like so:    

#include <boost/preprocessor/iteration/local.hpp>
#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_LIMITS     (0, CORE_NUM - 1)
#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_MACRO(n)   ITLB::CACHE itlb_ ## n ( "ITLB " #n, ITLB::cacheSize, ITLB::lineSize, ITLB::associativity);
#include BOOST_PP_LOCAL_ITERATE()

Comment: At one time I tried to do something the way you are trying here. It started making my code cumbersome and messy. When I realized I could use an array instead, I wondered why I didn't think of an array in the first place, dumped the separate variable approach and never looked back. I'm trying to help you over the next hurdle with less pain.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need every ITLB object to actually store `cacheSize`, `lineSize`, etc. constants?  That seems like a big waste, unless you're simulating heterogeneous multicore (big.LITTLE).

It may be better to set things up so code that uses these objects sees the `ITLB::associativity` constants.

Like Avi Berger's answer suggests, you should use a vector or something to hold the ITLBs, so you can iterate over them instead of having to copy/paste code to use four differently-named variables.

Since your number of cores is also a compile-time constant, you should use an array, not a `std::vector`, so there's zero overhead compared to accessing a single variable.

You probably shouldn't store `std::string` names in the object either.  Having them in an array lets you find its number by doing pointer math:

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#define MAX_CORE 4

struct ITLB {
    static const uint32_t page_size = 4*1024;
    static const uint32_t cacheSize = 32 * page_size;
    static const uint32_t associativity = 32;
    static const uint32_t max_sets = cacheSize / (page_size * associativity);

    // probably make this private
    struct { uint64_t from, to; } entries[max_sets][associativity];
    // write a default constructor if you want
};

static ITLB all_itlbs[MAX_CORE];  // or initialize with  = { ... };

void foo(ITLB *itlb) {
    std::cout << "Caller passed the ITLB for core " << itlb - all_itlbs;
    std::cout << "\nIts associativity is " << itlb->associativity << '\n';
}
```

This lets `ITLB` be a POD type, which will probably let the compiler make better code in some cases.

Writing your code with `static const` members lets you write code like `int foo = itlb->associativity;`, and have that be a compile-time constant.  But without changing the *users* of the code, `ITLB::page_size` could be a non-static member variable.  Users of the code wouldn't have to change to support heterogeneous ITLBs.

You'd need to take care in how access to `ITLB::entries` is done.  If `associativity` isn't a compile-time constant, it can't just be a multidimensional array.  You could still use a fixed-size array, and have the smaller TLBs leave some of it unused if you "simulate" multidimensional arrays with a flat array indexed like `entries[set * associativity + way_within_set]`.

BTW, this [actually compiles, and as you can see from the asm](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'+-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B11+-fverbose-asm+-O3++-march%3Dhaswell',source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdint%3E%0A%23define+MAX_CORE+4%0A%0Astruct+ITLB+%7B%0A++++static+const+uint32_t+page_size+%3D+4*1024%3B%0A++++static+const+uint32_t+cacheSize+%3D+32+*+page_size%3B%0A++++static+const+uint32_t+associativity+%3D+32%3B%0A++++static+const+uint32_t+max_sets+%3D+cacheSize+/+(page_size+*+associativity)%3B%0A%0A++++//+probably+make+this+private%0A++++struct+%7B+uint64_t+from,+to%3B+%7D+entries%5Bmax_sets%5D%5Bassociativity%5D%3B%0A++++//+write+a+default+constructor+if+you+want%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astatic+ITLB+all_itlbs%5BMAX_CORE%5D%3B++//+or+initialize+with++%3D+%7B+...+%7D%3B%0A%0Avoid+foo(ITLB+*itlb)+%7B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22Caller+passed+the+ITLB+for+core+%22+%3C%3C+itlb+-+all_itlbs%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22%5CnIts+associativity+is+%22+%3C%3C+itlb-%3Eassociativity+%3C%3C+!'%5Cn!'%3B%0A%7D%0A')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3), the `itlb - all_itlbs` calculation just turns into a subtraction and right shift by 9 (since `sizeof(ITLB)` is 512).

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you

```
#define fun(a, b, num) LOCALVAR ITLB::CACHE a ## num (#b " " #num, ITLB::cacheSize, ITLB::lineSize, ITLB::associativity)
fun(itlb_, ITLB, 0); 
fun(itlb_, ITLB, 1); 
fun(itlb_, ITLB, 2); 
fun(itlb_, ITLB, 3);
```

will expand to

```
LOCALVAR ITLB::CACHE itlb_0 ("ITLB" " " "0", ITLB::cacheSize, ITLB::lineSize, ITLB::associativity);
LOCALVAR ITLB::CACHE itlb_1 ("ITLB" " " "1", ITLB::cacheSize, ITLB::lineSize, ITLB::associativity);
LOCALVAR ITLB::CACHE itlb_2 ("ITLB" " " "2", ITLB::cacheSize, ITLB::lineSize, ITLB::associativity);
LOCALVAR ITLB::CACHE itlb_3 ("ITLB" " " "3", ITLB::cacheSize, ITLB::lineSize, ITLB::associativity);
```

the "ITLB" " " "0" part is equivalent with "ITLB 0"

not so graceful and maybe ugly, but it work as you want.

Comment: that sould works, but i dont know the number of the cores, so i have to put it on a for loop for i=0 to CORE_NUM, is it possible to do it? Check to Code Link above? it's not in main()...

Comment: no, you cannot do that, macro will be expanded before compile time, but the for loop may be dealt at the compile time. I do not get a good approach to deal with the problem, maybe you can write a script (bash , python,etc) to generate the file.